# mysql: select and sum of multiple datasets

Tags: mysql

I have the following data scheme in table 'example':

```
State | Identifier | Data  
true  |     A      |  60  
false |     B      |  20  
false |     A      |  10  
true  |     C      |  20  
true  |     A      |  40  
true  |     B      |  9  
true  |     C      |  30  
false |     A      |  60
```

What I want is to get a sum of each identifier, for example if its state is true.

For example A shall have a sum of 100, B a sum of 9 and C sum would be 50.
For a single identifier my sql query looks like

```
SELECT SUM(data) FROM example WHERE state = false AND identifier = "A"
```

which works just fine.

But, since the required identifiers will be delivered by a form which can be selected by checkboxes, the amount and value of the identifiers change.
I would like to get the result of the chosen identifiers A and C for example showing as `A=100 and C=50`

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance,

devyn

Comment: Just use `GROUP BY`, i.e.: `SELECT SUM(data) FROM example WHERE State = false AND Identifier = "A" GROUP BY Identifier `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to you `GROUP BY` clause, use this

```
SELECT Identifier, SUM(data) FROM example WHERE state = 'false' GROUP BY Identifier
```

I hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can group the rows returned by the column `Identifier`, i.e.:

```
SELECT
    SUM(Data)
FROM
    example
WHERE
    State = false AND
    Identifier = "A"
GROUP BY
    Identifier
```

Answer (score 0):

The get the result in **one row** you can use *conditional aggregation*:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN identifier = 'A' THEN data END) AS A_data,
       SUM(CASE WHEN identifier = 'B' THEN data END) AS B_data,
       SUM(CASE WHEN identifier = 'C' THEN data END) AS C_data
FROM example 
WHERE state = false
```